# Not removing `"\n"`, but keeping separate strings

Tags: ruby

I want my `split` method to keep the newline characters instead of removing them. For example, `receipt` text is this:

```
receipt = "rpples 1.29\nperrs 1.69\nrsprrrgus 2.19\ngrhpes 1.85\nlettuce 6.87\nstrrwberries 2.79\nbroccoli 1.66"
```

I want `receipt.split(" ")`, which currently returns:

```
"rpples", "1.29", "perrs", "1.69", "rsprrrgus", "2.19", "grhpes", "1.85", "lettuce", "6.87", "strrwberries", "2.79", "broccoli", "1.66"
```

to return instead:

```
"rpples", "1.29", "\n", "perrs", "1.69", "\n", "rsprrrgus", "2.19", "\n","grhpes", "1.85", "\n", "lettuce", "6.87", "\n", "strrwberries", "2.79", "\n", "broccoli", "1.66"
```

So when I use a `join` method at the end (after running another method in between to correct all the misspellings), the final text will be:

```
"rpples 1.29\nperrs 1.69\nrsprrrgus 2.19 ..."
```

instead of:

```
"rpples 1.29 perrs 1.69 rsprrrgus 2.19 grhpes 1.85 lettuce 6.87 strrwberries 2.79 broccoli 1.66"
```

without the `"\n"` characters. Please let me know how to keep the newline format when using the `split` method.

Comment: I think this is an XY-question. You shouldn't use `split`. You should use `gsub`.

Comment: Overwriting a basic method like `split` is a bad practice. Furthermore, besides that, the specification of your `split` is not clear. Why does it separate around `"\n"` when you explicitly pass `" "` as an argument? And finally, when you `join` the array, how do you know when to insert a space and when not?

Answer (score 1):

```
receipt.split(/ |(?<=\n)|(?=\n)/)
```

Split on space, before newline, or after newline.

Comment: @O-I: Only one: it does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: this will generate white spaces if you have more that one space separating the words

Comment: @Mircea: correct. The OP didn't specify the behaviour for such a case though.

Comment: That's cool. I like your solution :) And you can make it handle multiple spaces pretty easily

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `receipt.split(/ |(\n)/)`?

Comment: @Stefan: It is; completely forgot about it. If you submit, I promise you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28933433/477037) - you can use a capture group to include the separator (or one of the separators) in the result:

```
receipt.split(/ |(\n)/)
#=> ["rpples", "1.29", "\n", "perrs", "1.69", "\n", ...]
```

This will split by space (without capturing it) and by newline (with capturing it).